# Rendering thai characters with tags breaks on Apple devices?

Tags: php, html, iphone, thai

I'm trying to render Thai characters with tags wrapped around them:

So for instance: (*อ*ัน)

```
<i>อ</i>ัน
```

I want to display the character between the italics in a different color. Works fine on my Windows machine and my Android phone. But on iPhone and Mac the the superscript characters get rendered separately and not above the character in the italics.

Screenshot below testing with different tags. The one displaying correctly there has NO tags.

[screenshot](http://en-th.langnova.com/img/screenie.jpg)

Removing the tags renders correctly everywhere. Not sure at what level this issue is, but on iPhone have tried multiple browsers, FF, Chrome, Safari and on Mac as well and it seems to be display incorrectly there.

EDIT: The only workaround I have found for this so far is to overlay the characters with a duplicate copy without the superscript characters. However this is not exactly nice and sometimes a bit messy. Still looking for solution here if there is one.

Comment: Why not wrapped superscript too?

Comment: The little "0" under the superscript character is incorrect, it's a placeholder since the device can't render it correctly above the adjacent (previous) character. The issue is that I DON'T want that superscript character highlighted ;)

Comment: are you try to convert this in window1252 encoding?

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon Convert string to window1252 encoding...

Comment: @DipenChudasama Sorry, I does not mean you. I mean Rob.

Comment: I thought if you convert to HTML entities (&#3629;&#3633;&#3609;) then wrap a b tag around the first one it would work. But it failed in Safari and Firefox (macOS).

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert this string in `window1252 encoding`, this will understand and get exactly as it is character.

Hope this will help you.